# Spooling Oracle XML data results in 1 line and missing data?

Tags: oracle, xml

I am trying to spool Oracle XML data to a file but the resulting file ends up with 1 line which is stops after a certain amount of characters so doesn't contain all of the data?

```
set colsep ,
set feedback off
set headsep off
set linesize 32767
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on

spool $FILE

select
  xmlelement("apiRequest",
    xmlelement("orders",
      xmlagg(
        xmlelement("order",
          xmlelement("no", orders.order_no),
          xmlelement("date", orders.date),
          xmlelement("orderItems",
            xmlagg(
              xmlelement("orderItem",
                xmlelement("position", order_items.item_position)
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  as xml
from
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably hitting the default ["long" data type display limit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699121) of 80 characters:

> `SET LONG {80 | n}`
>
> Sets maximum width (in bytes) for displaying CLOB, LONG, NCLOB and XMLType values; and for copying LONG values.

Comment: Is there any way for Oracle to format the XML properly (i.e. indentation, line breaks etc.) when spooling to a file?

Comment: Not in SQL*Plus, but [in SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/us-en/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html)

Comment: XML does not need indentations.  Humans do.  The Oracle SQL function you are looking for is `XMLSERIALIZE()`

Comment: @mustaccio What value should I set `LONG` to? I have tried `2000000000` but now I am seeing random line breaks in my XML.